Google Docs asking me to grant view permissions to public doc
I have a bunch of guitar chord chart documents on Google Drive. They are all public ("anyone with the link can view"), all in the same public folder (also "anyone with the link can view").
Despite this, I get several emails every week saying some random person on the internet is requesting access to the document. Here's a snippet of a recent email:

That document is public, as is its containing folder. The user requesting access has a Google account, as you can see from the above screenshot they're requesting access from their @gmail address.
If I click "Manage sharing", this is what I see:

Here is the link the to document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/0B92G2WnQOLzhLUJYZDdTaGFVYjA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105518981459413120650&resourcekey=0-2KOhDMQGnXJaA1P_HtY5Sw&rtpof=true&sd=true
This document is available to anyone; I can even open it in an Incognito browser tab not signed in.
Why does Google Docs continue to send me emails saying peole are requesting access to the doc, given it's totally public?
Note: This related WebApps question is similar to my question, but differs in an important area: my question deals with public, anyone-with-the-link-can-view docs.

Theory: Google Drive recently introduced the idea of resource keys to access docs. The link to my doc contains a resource key. However, if I try to access it without a resource key in the URL, then I get an unauthorized error. Maybe the answer, then, is that someone is finding old links to these docs (via search engine?) that doesn't contain the resource key?

It's very likely that you are getting those email because some users are clicking "Request edit access"


Thanks, that is possible. It's just really weird that I'd get a dozen people every week clicking "request access" when they're looking at the document itself. Maybe people completely misunderstand what that button does.
